# Custom Camera screen orientation issue in android

Tags: android

I am making an android app which is based on video recording. And i am stuck with the issue of screen orientation which is not working properly, so suggest some solution to make my custom camera screen orientation fit with any android device. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Subham..Please share ur code which have u tried and share urs error log..Than we are able to help u man...For that u need to edit urs question

Comment: Are you using Camera2 ? If so, have a look at this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892093/10159898